# GROMACS OpenCl Cmake error: detected version mismatch between HWLOC headers and library

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, installation

I first downloaded GROMACS with conda, but found out that it does not recognize my GPU. My system is running ubuntu 19.10 with ryzen 3600x & Radeon RX Vega 56. I tried compiling gromacs myself following instructions on http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2019-rc1/install-guide/index.html, and  with the following cmake command:

cmake .. -DGMX_GPU=on -DGMX_USE_OPENCL=on, but I have the wrong "hwloc" version (See picture 1 for error)

Anyone have some ideas how I can work around this, or if there is some other way to make gromacs recgonize my GPU.(That's the problem in essence)

Completely new to Stack, compiling and linux in general. This is probably not the right place to post about this problem, but I'm in desperate need of some assistance.

[Screenshot of cmake error -wrong hwloc versioon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X6pv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've check the manual a bit, and try to follow the instruction of [where to install gromacs](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2019-rc1/install-guide/index.html#where-to-install-gromacs).

The error message itself seems that [path to the headers and to the libraries aren't set correctly.](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2019-rc1/install-guide/index.html#helping-cmake-find-the-right-libraries-headers-or-programs)

You want eventually define those variables in the CMakeList.txt, give it as calling arguments, or as instructed, define them as ENV variables.